# How do I forecast using ANN in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My project is to forecast the wti crude oil price using ann. I already have the dataset and I divided it into 70% training data and 30% testing data. That's the only basic thing I know and I did for my project. Now I dunno what to do next since I don't have any tutorial or guidance I can refer to. Can anyone tell me what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have TrainData, TargetTrain, TestData and TargetTest.
**TrainData and TestData samples are in row and features are in column.**

**TargetTrain and TargetTest are two classes and are 0 or 1**

```
InputNum=size(TrainData,2);
OutputNum=2;  % two class problem

Xtr=TrainData;
Ytr=full(ind2vec(double(TargetTrain+1)));
Xts=TestData;
Yts=full(ind2vec(double(TargetTest+1)));
%% Network Structure
net = feedforwardnet(11);
%% Training
net.trainParam.showWindow=1;
net.trainParam.max_fail=7;
net = train(net,Xtr',Ytr);
```

For evaluation you can test:

```
out_train=net(Xtr');
out_test=net(Xts');
```

This code create ANN with 11 hidden nets.